# Can netcat listen to a port of a remote computer?

Tags: sockets, unix, netcat

I am relaying the output of my script to a local port in my system viz -

$python script.py | nc 127.0.0.1 8033

Let's assume that my computer has ip 10.0.0.3

Now, Is it possible that some other computer (say IP 10.0.0.4) can listen to this port via nc or anything else. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.  The program listening on the port must be on the local machine (meaning 10.0.0.3 in your example).  You could arrange for a program on the local machine to listen and send the information to another machine, but the socket connection can only be established on the host.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I did try that before raising the question. Is there something else besides netcat who could listen to remote ports? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No - the design of sockets is such that your program has to be on the machine where you want to open it.

Comment: Provided your machine is on the subnet as your remote machine, you *could* use something like WireShark to watch the packets go by. But these days most networks are switched, which means that your machine will only ever get packets that are explicitly addressed to it (and broadcast packets), so making it impossible to eavesdrop on another computer. You'd have to try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

I use Perl to do exactly this - you could use python, of course.

In Perl, I use the `IO::Socket::INET` library.

I instantiate a new instance of `INET` with the `IP`, `port` and `Protocol`, and a time out for the `comms`. I then use the `recv` method to read data from that socket.

It's not as simple as nc; I wish NC did this - it would be a lot easier :)

Here's an outline of the actual Perl

---

```
my $data;
my socket;

$socket=IO::Socket::INET->new( PeerAddr => 10.0.0.3, PeerPort-> 8033, Proto => "tcp", Timeout => 1 ) or die "Unable to open port";

$socket->recv($data,bytes_to_read); # Put your chosen read size in stead of bytes_to_read
print $data;
```

---